# 'Timeout was reached' network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, l2tp

I'm trying to connect to a l2tp w/ psk VPN using Ubuntu but i keep getting timeout (after less than 10 secs) was reached when trying to connect:

```
sending packet: from 192.168.0.100[4500] to 201.22.XXX.XX[4500] (68 bytes)
Dec 11 18:41:00 user NetworkManager[43772]: <warn>  [1702330860.0702] vpn[0x55ba64c8f620,65095f09-a183-46cc-ba6c-c12eff476937,"VPN-NAME"]: failed to connect: 'Timeout was reached'
```

PS: **The timeout is set to 60 seconds, i've already check**